# irreducible components of subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a closed immersion of (noetherian) schemes.

Is there any "general" result on $f$ out there ensuring that $X$ has the same number of irreducible components as $Y$ ?

Comment: No, because it is quite untrue. For instance, if $Y$ is an irreducible component of $X$, then $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X$. In particular, there is a closed immersion $Y\to X$ and $Y$ has only one irreducible component.

Comment: Well, I know this is not true in general... but that does not answer my question, isn't it ?

Comment: Ah. I am sorry, I get the point now. You want a sufficient condition on $f$ for $X$ to have the same number of irreducible components as $Y$. I can think of ways to rephrase this, but none of those are useful, most likely. Let's hope someone else knows a handy condition.

Comment: Indeed, maybe (and I am quite certain of that) my question was not formulated very well.

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion: this is a question with courious answers!, I propose two conditions: a sufficient condition and a (quasi) necessary condition.

**Quasi necessary condition:** for all $x\in X,\,f^{\sharp}_x:\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is an isomorphism; in this way the irreducible components of $X$ in which $x$ is contained are in bijection with the irreducible components of $Y$ in which $f(x)$ is contained (for a proof, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674660/minimal-prime-ideals-of-mathcal-o-x-x-correspond-to-irreducible-components/1675889#1675889)), and in this way one uses the hypothesis of Noetherianess of $Y$ (and $X$).

But this condition is equivalent to say that $f$ is an open immersion; see *E.G.A., chapitre I, proposition 4.2.2.(a)*.

For exact, a **necessary condition** is that for all $x\in X,\,f^{\sharp}_x$ induces a bijection between the sets of minimal prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}$.

**Sufficient condition:** $f$ induces a homeomorphism between the underlying topological spaces $|X|$ and $|Y|$ of $X$ and $Y$.

**Warning:** if $f$ satisfies the second condition then $f$ does not need to be an isomorphism of schemes; indeed, for **example**: for any *non-reduced* scheme $Z$, one can consider the associated reduced scheme $Z_{red}$; there exists a canonical closed immersion (of schemes) $i:Z_{red}\to Z$, $i$ is not an isomorphism of schemes even though $|Z|=|Z_{red}|$, and $i$ does not need to be an open immersion (of schemes).